# Dart - browser hanging when looping

Tags: dart

Hey I was wondering how I would go about looping something with out hanging the browser.

I want to increase an int by 1 every second.

I have tried using dart:isolate but it gives errors when using spawnFunction();
I sore somewhere that you now have to use Isolate.spawn(). but there does not seem to be much information on this. either that or I cant find any.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Timer, like so:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  var div =   querySelector("#my-div");
  int count = 0;
  new Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 1), (_) {
    div.text = (count++).toString();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User a periodic Timer object.

```dart
Timer t = Timer.periodic( new Duration(milliseconds:1000),  myCodeFluff);
```

then later

```dart
int i = 0; // outside as a class attribute.

void myCodeFluff( Timer theOriginalTimer) {
  ++i;
  querySelector("#myText").text = i.toString();
  if ( i > 100)
       theOriginalTimer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have imported "dart:async" and I am getting an error saying periodic is not defined for the class Timer. do i have to import something else? or am I missing something?